# All Time reputations ranking is several days out of date

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-leagues

The [All Time reputations ranking on SO](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow) hasn't been updated with new data since late last week (Friday or Saturday).

Reputation report:

```
-- 2012-06-01 rep +220  = 40375     
 1  10848214 (15)
 2  10848214 (10)
 2  10860128 (10)
 2  10856913 (10)
 2  10860128 (10)
 2  10861923 (10)
 2   7919280 (10)
 2   5755124 (10)
 2  10861923 (10)
 2  10861923 (10)
 2  10862931 (10)
 2  10862931 (10)
 2  10862931 (10)
 2  10862931 (10)
-- 2012-06-02 rep +145  = 40520     
 2  10862931 (10)
 1  10717533 (15)
 2  10870133 (10)
 2  10873700 (10)
 2  10873700 (10)
-- 2012-06-03 rep +55   = 40575     
 2  10874130 (10)
 2  10874130 (10)
 2  10876719 (10)
 1  10879366 (15)
 2  10879366 (10)
 2  10879366 (10)
 2  10880326 (5)
 1   9044251 (15)
 3  10881204 (-2)
-- 2012-06-04 rep +83   = 40658
```

Screenshot of rep leagues:

[image: mKorbel's all time ranking]

Comment: @jadarnel27: I think the OP is complaining that they haven't been updated in several days (which I had already noticed myself).

Comment: Oh, thanks @OliCharlesworth.  That makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good catch. This has been fixed.

A recent change introduced this bug: All-time leagues (and only all-time leagues) were being cached for a week, rather than until UTC midnight, as are the rest of the currently ongoing leagues.

Comment: not sure, but I think that updates were periodically there not only once per day, please my question [Point](http://stackoverflow.com/users/714968/mkorbel?tab=tags) are updated periodically ???

Comment: @mKorbel Sorry, I can't figure out what you're asking here.

Comment: What would it take for it to be updated more often?